# Lua: Custom iterator to sort by color?

Tags: sorting, lua, iterator

I would like to create a custom iterator that will sort by the color and number values within this table:

```
t1 = {{"green", 1},{"red", 3},{"green", 2},{"yellow", 5},{"red", 4}}

for i, v in ipairs(t1) do
     Note(i," ",v[1]," ",v[2])
end
```

Right now this will output:

```
1 green 1
2 red 3
3 green 2
4 yellow 5
5 red 4
```

My desired output is:

```
4 yellow 5
3 green 2
1 green 1
5 red 4
2 red 3
```

Can I achieve this with a custom iterator?

EDIT: I was going for something like this, but I just can't seem to work it out:

```
function sort_colours(t) -- sort table
    local T = { }
    for i, v in ipairs(t) do
        T[#T + 1] = { i = i, v = v }
    end

    local order = {yellow = 1, green = 2, red = 3} -- desired order for colors
table.sort(T, function(a, b)
    -- since you seem to want large-to-small when colors are the same,
    -- use b[2] < a[2] comparison
    if a[1] == b[1] then return b[2] < a[2] end
    return order[a[1]] < order[b[1]]
  end)
    for i = 1, #T do
        T[i] = T[i].i
    end
        local i = 0
    return function() -- iterator function
        i = i + 1
        if T[i] then
            return T[i], t[T[i]]
        end
    end
end

local t1 = {{"green", 1},{"red", 3},{"green", 2},{"yellow", 5},{"red", 4}}

for k, v in sort_colours(t1) do print(k, v[1], v[2]) end
```

Comment: Why yellow before green/red? Why green before red? I'm having trouble seeing the logic behind that part.

Comment: May be it http://www.colormatters.com/color-and-design/basic-color-theory. But what color first? I like red :)

Comment: It was supposed to be like a traffic light!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your try is very close. You just have to remember that the `a` and `b` parameters in the comparison function to `table.sort` refer to elements of the `T` array, which have `i` and `v` fields (and the `v` field contains the values that you actually want to compare):

```
function sort_colours(t)
    local T = { }
    for i, v in ipairs(t) do
        T[#T+1] = { i = i, v = v } -- could just use T[i] here!
    end
    local order = {yellow = 1, green = 2, red = 3}
    table.sort(T, function(a, b)
        if a.v[1] == b.v[1] then return b.v[2] < a.v[2] end
        return order[a.v[1]] < order[b.v[1]]
    end)
    local i = 0
    return function()
        i = i + 1
        if T[i] then
            return T[i].i, T[i].v
        end
    end
end


local t1 = {{"green", 1},{"red", 3},{"green", 2},{"yellow", 5},{"red", 4}}

for k, v in sort_colours(t1) do print(k, v[1], v[2]) end
```

The second `for` loop in your code (`for i = 1, #T do T[i] = T[i].i end`) is unnecessary because you basically throw away most of the data you just sorted. But what I think you tried to do is a common approach to this kind of problem: create (and sort) an array of indices into the original array, and don't duplicate the data itself. Here is an example (to make things interesting as a more general/reusable function this time):

```
-- default compare function
local function lessthan(a, b)
    return a < b
end

function sorted_ipairs(t, f)
    f = f or lessthan
    local indices = {}
    for i in ipairs(t) do
        indices[i] = i
    end
    table.sort(indices, function(a, b)
        return f(t[a], t[b])
    end )
    local i = 1
    return function()
        local index = indices[i]
        if index then
            i = i + 1
            return index, t[index]
        end
    end
end

local order = {yellow = 1, green = 2, red = 3}
local function colour_compare(a, b)
    if a[1] == b[1] then return b[2] < a[2] end
    return order[a[1]] < order[b[1]]
end
for k, v in sorted_ipairs(t1, colour_compare) do print(k, v[1], v[2]) end
```

Both approaches work the same as long as the original array doesn't change during the iteration. If it does (either because you add/remove elements, or because a badly behaved `__index` metamethod is involved), the first approach is more predictable, because it works on a snapshot of the data.

For the sample data the output is the same in both cases:

```
4   yellow  5
3   green   2
1   green   1
5   red 4
2   red 3
```

Comment: My only problem with this answer is you modify the original table during your iteration call.

Comment: Nevermind, I read your code wrong. I was fairly tired 15 hours ago.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the reason for your code or how you are implementing it, I've made an iterator which should work for the majority of the time. Unless you're using clones really weirdly, as pointed out by siffiejoe in the comments.

My method works around creating a clone of the table and sorting it, and then returning an iterator so that you can call it in a generic for:

```
t1 = {{"green", 1},{"red", 3},{"green", 2},{"yellow", 5},{"red", 4}}

function ByColor(t,order)
   local order = order or {yellow=1,green=2,red=3}
   local nt = {table.unpack(t)}
   table.sort(nt, function(a,b)
      order[a[1]] < order[b[1]] or order[a[1]] == order[b[1]] and a[2] > b[2]
   end)
   local helper = 1
   return function(ti,v)
      local nxt = nt[helper]
      helper = helper + 1
      for i,v in ipairs(t) do
         if v == nxt then
            return i,nxt
         end
      end
      return nil
   end
end

for i,v in ByColor(t1) do
   print(i,v[1],v[2])
end
```

It returns the actual indices in your table, and provides an optional argument for the order, assuming you want to switch from yellow/green/red.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to sort a table and then iterate it via `next`, because `next` doesn't guarantee a particular ordering. Also your way of figuring out the original index will fail if there are identical elements in the original table (e.g. try `t1[#t1+1] = t1[3]`. And you *really* like the `{table.unpack()}` trick, don't you?! ;-)

Comment: @siffiejoe I fixed the next problem, not because of it not working (because it does) but for efficiency. Also I fail to see why he'd add clones to the table, but I noted it in the answer, and yes, I do love that trick :)

Comment: The comparator seems to be missing an equality check in second part to the `or` like this: `order[a[1]] < order[b[1]] or order[a[1]] == order[b[1]] and a[2] > b[2]`

Comment: @wqw If it's order is less then it will pick a, otherwise (if it's equal or greater) it picks the one with the greatest 2nd index. Adding an == is irrelevant.

Comment: @warspyking Actually @wqw is correct. With the comparison function as it is right now `{ "green", 3 } < { "red", 4 }` (because green things come before red things) **but also** `{ "red", 4 } < { "green", 3 }` (because `4 > 3`).

Comment: @siffie But it will never evaluate [2] > [2] if the original condition returns true. Give me a minute to find a link.

Comment: @warspyking: The comparison function should return `true` if the first argument is considered less than the second argument. If  the color of `a` is less than the color of `b`, your function returns the correct result. However, if the color of `a` is greater than the color of `b` the function should always return `false`, but it tests `a[2] > b[2]` anyway. Just run your code and compare it with the desired output in the question. And then switch the second and the third element of `t1`, run your code again, and compare the output with the previous result. You'll see what's wrong ...

Comment: @siffie Oh my gosh I just caught that. My bad I'm just an idiot haha. Give me 20 sec to fix my answer

Comment: Thanks everybody, this was all very helpful for me understanding iterators, which was the reason behind my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a table with the desired order and resort the table before iterating using a standard `ipairs`:

```
local t1 = {{"green", 1},{"red", 3},{"green", 2},{"yellow", 5},{"red", 4}}
local order = {yellow = 1, green = 2, red = 3} -- desired order for colors
table.sort(t1, function(a, b)
    -- since you seem to want large-to-small when colors are the same,
    -- use b[2] < a[2] comparison
    if a[1] == b[1] then return b[2] < a[2] end
    return order[a[1]] < order[b[1]]
  end)
for k, v in ipairs(t1) do print(k, v[1], v[2]) end -- show the result
```

I get the following result, which is probably what you want:

```
1   yellow  5
2   green   2
3   green   1
4   red 4
5   red 3
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this that doesn't change the way the table is indexed?